# Convert to lat-lon coordinates GDAL

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I have a `netCDF` file and would like to convert it to `LAT-LON` coordinates.
1) I do not know the `projection` in the file but from the [website](https://weather.gc.ca/grib/grib2_RDPA_ps10km_e.html) of the data provider, the data is on a `polar-stereographic (PS) grid` covering North America and adjacent waters with a 10 km resolution at 60 degrees north.
2) How can I project to `latlon` using a suitable coordinate system for the north pole?

Here is my sample file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgni1s5tgu1sbwh/data.nc?dl=0

Comment: Any chance of something smaller than 750Mb to download? Maybe just a few coordinate points in the given coordinate system?

Comment: @Spacedman I just added a smaller file size `3MB

Comment: Unfortunately, GDAL 2.1.0 can not read the reduced file.

Answer (score 1):

The projection looks like it matches this custom entry in http://spatialreference.org:

```
PROJCS["Stereographic_North_Pole",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
        DATUM["D_unknown",
            SPHEROID["Sphere",6371229,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Stereographic_North_Pole"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",60],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",249],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/8237/

Depending on the software you have at hand, that should be usable in one format or another.

If you want to transform a shapefile in lat-long to this grid system, then try this:

```
require(rgdal)
target = "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=249 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371229 +b=6371229 +units=m +no_defs"
shgrid = spTransform(shlatlong, CRS(target))
```

plot the `shgrid` object to make sure. You might get problems if the shapefile crosses the dateline or rounds the pole...

Not knowing how you've loaded your netCDF into R, I can't be sure how to crop it, but if its a raster then `mask` from the `raster` package probably does the trick.

Comment: it is true that It might not be a good idea to transform a grid over the pole to lat-long but I have a shapefile in latlong which I would like to use in cropping the netcdf file. Here are the bbox coordinates of the shapefile:        
`xmin -141.01807 xmax -52.61941`
`ymin 41.68144  ymax 83.13550`  Can you show me how to use these coordinates to crop the file attached here? I can also include the shapefile in the attachment if you need it.

Comment: Do you have QGIS, ArcGIS, R, something else, or do you want to do all this with GDAL command-line tools?

Comment: I have R. I can use raster and rasterVis packages for doing it if you give me directions. `gdaltransform -s_srs SR-ORG:8237 -t_srs epsg:5937 2013_000_CaPA_continental_v2.3-analyse_final_10km_6h_APCP.nc 2013.tif` gdal does not recognize SR-ORG:8237. It issues an error.

Comment: `target` flips my map upside down. It is a map of Canada

Comment: Ooh. Possibly because the grid system reference has Y increasing southwards (on the Canadian side of the pole anyway). Sorry, but I can't download a 750Mb file to play with this.

Comment: Here is my code: `dat<- raster('2013_000_CaPA_continental_v2.3-analyse_final_10km_6h_APCP.nc')`# read one layer only for illustration;

print(dat) # print netcdf details;
`proj4string(dat) <- CRS"unknown";`

`projj <- CRS("+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=249 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371229 +b=6371229 +units=m +no_defs"`);
`rx <- projectRaster(from=dat, crs=projj)`



`cr <- crop(rx, extent(Prairie.Boundaries))` ;
`fr <- rasterize(shapfile, cr) `;
`Can <- mask(x=cr, mask=fr);`;

Comment: I just replaced the larger file with a much smaller subset (just one timestep) from the rasterBrick. Hopefully you can use this to help me out

Answer (score 0):

To reproject raster into another spatial reference the [gdalwarp](http://gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) utility can be used. The command can be looks like:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs 'EPSG:4326' -overwrite \
NETCDF:"your file.nc":your_subdataset subdataset_4326.tif
```

Choose another projection if you wish.